# Nodejs app suddenly started to act differently

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nodemon

This part of code handles the login authorization routing in my app

```
const express = require("express");
const authController = require('../controllers/authController');
const indexController = require('../controllers/indexController');
const router = express.Router();

router.use("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.session.loggedIn) {
    res.redirect('/account');
  }
  next();
});

router.use("/account", (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.session.loggedIn) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
});

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('/login');
});
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login');
});
router.get('/log-out', authController.logOut);
router.get("/account", indexController.getAccountData);

module.exports = router;
```

There were no problems and it was working fine till recent days.

I haven't change anything in this file nor `authController` nor `indexController`.
When I make a change (in other parts), `nodemon` restarts the app and I automatically jump to login page cause obviously all sessions are destroyed. But I get an error in `getAccountData` function (Error says req.session is undefined).

As you can see there's no way for the app to reach that function with no sessions set.

I have to restart the app again to act correct.

Answer (score 0):

`req.session.loggedIn` would error out whenever session is undefined. You need to check if it is defined before trying to access `loggedIn`.

Try:

```
router.use("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  if(req.session && req.session.loggedIn) {
    res.redirect('/account');
  }
  next();
});

router.use("/account", (req, res, next) => {
  if(!req.session || !req.session.loggedIn) {
    res.redirect('/login');
  }
  next();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but didn't work. The error is not about `req.session.loggedIn`. It runs the function `getAccountData`, which shouldn't. And the error belongs with there.

Comment: To confirm, did you change this for both instances of `req.session.loggedIn`? THere is one for the /account path as well. It should error out when session is missing.

Comment: Yes I did for both. I'm telling what exactly console is telling about the error. It is in that function

Comment: In this case I think you need to post the login function.

Answer (score 0):

##### The session will be cleared each time the server restarts. So to escape from that you need to save the session to database. If you are using mongodb or I can give you example using mongodb.

```js
import MongoStore from "connect-mongo";
import session from "express-session";

app.use(
  session({
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost:27017/project",
    }),
    secret: "secret key",
    cookie: { maxAge: sessionExpireInMilliseconds },
  })
);
```